# Asynchronous NSURLConnection breaks timers

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have a class set up to handle my web API calls.  This is done using an `NSMutableURLRequest` and an `NSRLlConnection`.  I initially used `connectionWithRequest: delegate:` and that worked well for the most part, except when I depended on this request being truly asynchronous, not just partially executing in the main run loop.

To do this, I thought I would just use the ever so convenient `sendAsynchronousRequest: queue: completionHandler:` and at first in all of my unit tests I thought this worked great.  It performed asynchronously, my semaphores were waited on and signaled correctly, it was great.

Until I tried to re-use this new modified version of my Web service class in my actual app.  Part of my app plays a video and uses a repeating `NSTimer` to update part of the screen based on the current playback time of the video.  For some unknown reason, as long as I have executed at least one of these new asynchronous `NSURLConnection`s both the video playback and the timer no longer work.

Here is how I initialize the connection:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestMessage
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
                       {
                           if ( data.length > 0 && connectionError == nil )
                           {
                               _webServiceData = [data mutableCopy];
                               [self performSelector:@selector(connectionDidFinishLoading:) withObject:nil];
                           }
                           else if ( connectionError != nil )
                           {
                               _webServiceData = [data mutableCopy];
                               [self performSelector:@selector(webServiceDidFinishExecutingWithError:) withObject:connectionError];
                           }
                       }];
```

Here is how I initialize my repeating timer:

```
playbackTimeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkPlaybackTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And I have absolutely no idea why the asynchronous `NSURLConnection` is causing aspects of my app that are completely unrelated to stop functioning.

**EDIT:**

For clarification I have `ViewControllerA` that performs the web requests to retrieve some data.  When that data is successfully retrieved, `ViewControllerA` automatically segues to `ViewControllerB`.  In `ViewControllerB`'s `viewWillAppear` is where I set up my movie player and timer.

Comment: Why are you using `performSelector:withObject:` (`[self performSelector:@selector(connectionDidFinishLoading:) withObject:nil];`) instead of calling the method directly (`[self connectionDidFinishLoading:nil]`)?

Comment: I must have been thinking I needed to do it on the main thread and forgot to switch it back

Comment: `performSelector:withObject:` will execute the method on the current thread, not the main thread.  Did you mean to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` instead?

Comment: Probably, it works as is, I can try switching it to main thread, or just calling the method directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the future, do not use semaphores to make the test wait. Use the new `XCTestExpectation`, which is designed for testing asynchronous processes.

   And unlike the traditional semaphore trick, using the test expectation doesn't block the main thread, so if you have completion blocks or delegates that require the main thread, you can do this in conjunction with the test expectation.
2. You're clearly doing something that isn't working because you're running this on the background queue. Typical problems include

   - If you were trying to run that timer from the background thread, that wouldn't work, unless you used one of the standard timer workarounds (scheduling it on main runloop, dispatching the creation of the timer back to main thread, using dispatch timer, etc.).

     Having earlier described these alternatives in great detail, it turns out you're initiating the timer from `viewWillAppear`, so that's all academic.
   - any UI updates (including performing segues, reloading tables, etc.).
   - care should be taken when synchronizing class properties updated from background thread (these might best be dispatched to main thread, too).

   Anyway, you might remedy this by just tell `sendAsynchronousRequest` to run its completion block on the main queue:

   ```
   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestMessage
                                      queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                          completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
       ...
   }];
   ```

   Then, the completion block would have run on the background queue, and everything would probably be fine. Or you can manually dispatch the calling of your completion handlers back to the main queue.

   But make sure that any UI updates (including the performing a segue programmatically) are run on the main thread (either by running the whole completion block on the main thread, or manually dispatching the relevant calls to the main thread).

Comment: I can't use a test expectation because I am testing authenticated web service calls.  The test MUST wait to execute until the authentication request has completed.  And every test needs the authentication, so I execute the authentication request in the setup phase

Comment: That's precisely what the expectation does. It holds the test until all of the asynchronous tasks are done (or it times out).

Comment: Also, the timer is executing in a `viewWillAppear` in a view controller

Comment: How I test asynchronous tasks aside, it doesn't explain why this asynchronous request is breaking a timer in a completely separated aspect of the application

Comment: They do some minor processing on the received data (if any) and then call a delegate method.  The particular case that I am working with where it is breaking the timer I have `VC A` which on load performs an authentication request, then preforms another request to retrieve data upon successful authentication.  When that data is successfully retrieved a segue is performed to `VC B` where in its `viewWillAppear` method the movie player and timer are set up.

Comment: The only "UI" related thing is a call to `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: And you of course dispatch that to the main thread? Because you're currently running those completion methods from background thread.

Comment: Unbelievable, calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from a background thread does cause issues.  Absolutely no errors or warnings or complaints and no other UI issues except for this timer and video thing

Comment: @DanF, the vast majority of the UIKit is not thread-safe. Calling UIKit methods from a background thread will cause lots of problems. Don't do it. As others have pointed out, it would be easy to make your completion  block run on the main queue. (That's what I would suggest). If you are determined to make the completion handler run on a background queue then you need to change your performSelector calls to `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`

Comment: Accepted this answer because it did lead me to the correct action: moved the completion callback to the main thread.  Question though: I thought that the queue you pass in was the queue that the request is executed on, not just where the completion handler is called.

Comment: It's the queue for the completion handler. It makes no claims or assurances as to which thread the connection uses.